# MSBuild.exe output encoding

Tags: c#, msbuild, utf

I use MSBuild.exe for building solution on machine with russian language. But in TeamCity build log all russian chars in wrong encoding. How to setup MSBuild.exe for properly output (UTF-8 for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check /fileloggerparameters command line parameter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx). It should be the same for console logger.

e.g. MyLog.log file with diagnostic verbosity using UTF-8 encoding:

```
/fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=MyLog.log;Encoding=UTF-8;Verbosity=diagnostic
```

Comment: Thats not solve TeamCity problem, but now I have a normal encoded log file. Thanks!

Comment: There's no Encoding option for /consoleloggerparameters msbuild parameter. As I used console output of msbuild in Jenkins, I had to change code page ([`chcp` command](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html))